# Setting the page's title and sitemap node to the same text with ASP.NET MVC Sitemap Provider

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3, mvcsitemapprovider, sitemapprovider

I'm using `ASP.NET MVC 3` and `ASP.NET MVC Sitemap Provider`.  I would like to set the view's title and the sitemap node to the same text.  How would I do this?  Where would it be done and are there any samples?

So if I have the following link /Product/Create then I would like the page title to be `Capture New Product`.  And the sitemap trail must look like `Home > Product > Capture New Product`.

How would one write tests for this in NUnit?  Are tests necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the view's title to SiteMap.CurrentNode.Title. This should do the trick.